# Эмулятор Android не видит IIS-сервер ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, сервер, xamarin

Пытаюсь получить доступ к серверу из приложения на эмуляторе андроид с помощью RestSharp:

```
public const string BaseUrl = "https://192.168.0.8:44317";

RestClient client = new RestClient($"{BaseUrl}/Friendly/GetUserById");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("id", id.ToString());

IRestResponse response = await client.ExecutePostTaskAsync(request);
```

Однако запрос до сервера не доходит. При этом, если сервер опубликован, то никаких проблем нет. IP для URL брал из консоли с помощью команды `ipconfig` из строки

```
IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.8
```

Порт брал из окна браузера, открывшегося при старте сервера. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скорее всего файрвол не пускает. Для проверки можете попробовать его временно выключить.

Comment: @ГеннадийП отключил, не помогло